# Receive WM_COPYDATA messages on Firemonkey form?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

I am in the process of porting a Windows VCL application to Windows FMX (Firemonkey) in Delphi XE7, and have been stuck on this one issue...

How do you receive messages such as WM_COPYDATA on a Firemonkey form?

I have `procedure WMCopyData(var msg: TWMCopyData); message WM_COPYDATA;` in the `protected` part of my form, but the message is never received. Identical code on VCL form works fine. I understand why it doesn't work (FMX doesnt use Windows message loops?), not sure of what to do about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FMX on Windows does indeed rely on the Windows message loop. But the architecture doesn't support message delivery using the `message` keyword.

In any case, your VCL code is a little flaky because it presumes that your form's window will not be re-created. It's perfectly plausible that the window will be re-created so using the form's window handle as a message recipient is a dubious practice.

The best way to work around that problem, and also to solve your FMX problem, is to create a window dedicated to the task of receiving these messages. If you control the window creation, then you can ensure that the window lives as long as you need it, and is not subject to VCL window re-creation.

On the Windows platform you can do this by calling [`AllocateHWnd`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.AllocateHWnd) from the `System.Classes` unit. Of course this is Windows specific, but then `WM_COPYDATA` is Windows specific so that's not going to be a concern for you.

Comment: There's no indication that the VCL code here is *flaky*, because you have no indication of how he finds the handle to which the WM_COPYDATA is being sent. If it's retrieved using `FindWindow` before sending the message, there's nothing at all wrong with it; there's no reason the window being recreated would be an issue, and nothing *dubious* about it.

Comment: @KenWhite That's not so. The window re-creation could happen between `FindWindow` returning, and the message being sent to that window.

Comment: Sure it could. And between the call to FindWindow and the message being sent, Armageddon could arrive. If you're using WM_COPYDATA to communicate between apps, you typically send the message and then, if you don't receive a reply within a reasonable time you simply send it again. A slim chance of failure under a rare circumstance does not qualify as *flaky* or *dubious*, IMO.

Comment: @KenWhite I think I'd always opt to be in control of the window handle's lifetime personally.

Comment: You still have the same initial problem: how to get that window handle from your app to the other app (the sender of WM_COPYDATA). How do you do that? (*FindWindow* again.)

Comment: @Ken One app might pass the window handle to the other app

Comment: Thanks, I ended up getting it working by using AllocateHWnd with a unique class name in the receiver app, and using FindWindow on that class name in the sender app to get the main handle and sending the WM_COPYDATA call to that handle.

Comment: Yes, the downside of AllocateHWnd is that you don't get to choose the class name. So that leads you to direct calls to RegisterClassEx and CreateWindowEx. Perhaps that's the best way. All wrapped up of course.

Comment: @David: Which is specifically what I mentioned in my last comment: How do you find the window handle to which you *might pass the window handle to the other app*? (*FindWindow again.)

Comment: @Ken FindWindow is one way, but not the only way by any means. Anyway, I take your point if FindWindow is the mechanism being used.